# Anonymous struct to boost function conversion fails on gcc 5.4

Tags: c++, gcc

This particular piece of code fails on gcc 5.4, but works on many others, msvc 2015, clang, and newer versions of gcc.

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef boost::function1<int, double> fn;

class fn_map : public std::map<std::string, fn> {
public:
    void reg(const std::string&, fn);
};

int main(int, char**) {
    fn_map fm;

    struct {
        int operator()(double v) {
            return static_cast<int>(v * 2.);
        }
    } factory;

    fm.reg("factory", factory);
}

void fn_map::reg(const std::string& nm, fn f) {
    this->insert(std::make_pair(nm, f));
}
```

Error message:

```
no known conversion for argument 2 from 'main(int, char**)::<anonymous struct>' to 'fn {aka boost::function1<int, double>}'
```

The last ubuntu LTS still has gcc 5, so if possible I'd like to have this code working there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `struct` definition out of the function definition into a non-anonymous type seems to work-around this particular issue on gcc.

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef boost::function1<int, double> fn;

class fn_map : public std::map<std::string, fn> {
public:
    void reg(const std::string&, fn);
};

namespace {
    struct factory_t {
        int operator()(double v) {
            return static_cast<int>(v * 2.);
        }
    };
}

int main(int, char**) {
    fn_map fm;

    factory_t factory;

    fm.reg("factory", factory);
}

void fn_map::reg(const std::string& nm, fn f) {
    this->insert(std::make_pair(nm, f));
}
```